# Adding class to an element got by classname

Tags: javascript, php, css

Trying to add a class to an element, I need to get by class name. Any idea why it is not working? (Using Wordpress Code Snippets in case someones wondering)

```php
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>

    <script>
        var myButton = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-toggle mobile-menu");
        myButton.classList.add(".teststyle");   
    </script>

    <style>
        .teststyle {} 
    </style>

<?php } );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 1):

You're querying for multiple elements, as class names are not unique, therefore you need to loop through them. Also, you don't need the selector-specific dot to specify a class when using `classList.add`.

This snippet should work, if your element has both the classes `menu-toggle` and `mobile-menu`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".menu-toggle.mobile-menu").forEach((element) => element.classList.add("teststyle"))
```

If the element with the class `mobile-menu` is a child of the element with the class `menu-toggle`, try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".menu-toggle.mobile-menu").forEach((element) => element.classList.add("teststyle"))
```

Edit:

As you're adding the script into the head, it'll be run before the HTML elements are loaded, so you need to defer the execution until the DOM is loaded.

You can either add the script after the elements in the DOM, or use the DOMContentLoaded event, e.g. like this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".menu-toggle.mobile-menu").forEach((element) => element.classList.add("teststyle"))
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This one sounds logical but for some reason the element does not get any new class.

Comment: Right. The issue is within your script placement. It will be run before the elements are added to the DOM. 

Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the response of a `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` is a NodeList. So basically you have to assign the value to a specific index of that NodeList.

In this case you should be getting an error in console that says something like

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

That happens because your NodeList doesn't have an element called `classList` and because of that the `add` function doesn't exist in that context.

Once you get the elements by class you get a NodeList element with all the corresponding elements and what you can do is:

```
myButton[0].classList.add("teststyle");
```

Also, here you don't need the point prefix for the class.

Here's an example.

```js
var myButton = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-toggle mobile-menu");

console.log(myButton);

console.log(myButton[0]);

myButton[0].classList.add("test-class");
```

```css
.test-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="menu-toggle mobile-menu">Button</button>
```

Comment: It's a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an Array.

Comment: Thankyou, it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined". Adding "const classes = x.classList" doesnt help

Comment: Have you tried adding the `[0]` index to your `myButton` usage? As I show you in the snippet.